# SQL Count if the record has never appear in previous timeline

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
customer_num    Grade   month   amount
2                100    5       12
2                100    5       65
2                100    5       47
1                200    6       54
2                100    6       34
1                200    6       76
1                200    6       56
2                100    6       23
4                200    7       34
3                200    7       32
3                200    7       32
1                200    7       45
```

I need to the SQL code to create the following output:

```
Grade   month   Number of payment   Number of New Customer
100     5           3                   1
100     6           2                   0
200     6           3                   1
200     7           4                   2
```

With the following definitions:

- Number of payment:   the total number of payments for this month/Grade
- New Customer:    The number of new customers which made the first payment in this month

Very much appreciate your help

Comment: Which SQL engine?

Comment: Microsoft SQL server

Comment: Can you explain why the "Number of New Customer" is 3 in the 1st row of your expected results?

Comment: You are right. It should be 1

Comment: And what about month = 6? Why 0 for Grade = 100 and 1 for Grade = 200?

Comment: Because in month 6, we have customer 2 (which is grade 100) making 2 payments and we know that customer 2 has already made payments in month 5 so it's not new customer so last column for grade 100 is 0

Comment: And there is one new customer (customer 1) in month 6 which is grade 200 who made 3 payment

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check this only [Number of New Customer] count not mapped following expected output.

> SQL Query

```
DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    customer_num    INT,
    Grade   INT,
    month   INT,
    amount INT
)
INSERT INTO @table VALUES(
2,100,5,12),
(2,100,5,65),
(2,100,5,47),
(1,200,6,54),
(2,100,6,34),
(1,200,6,76),
(1,200,6,56),
(2,100,6,23),
(4,200,7,34),
(3,200,7,32),
(3,200,7,32),
(1,200,7,45)

SELECT DISTINCT [month],
Grade,
COUNT(amount) AS [Number of payment],
COUNT(customer_num) AS [Number of New Customer]
FROM @table
GROUP BY Grade,[month]
```

> Output below

```
month       Grade       Number of payment Number of New Customer
----------- ----------- ----------------- ----------------------
5           100         3                 3
6           100         2                 2
6           200         3                 3
7           200         4                 4
```

[image]

Comment: To be honest, I had that part, my question is mainly with the last column

Answer (score 0):

With aggregation and a correlated subquery:

```
select t.Grade, t.Month, 
  count(*) [Number of payment],
  (
    select count(distinct tt.customer_num) from tablename tt
    where tt.Month = t.Month and tt.Grade = t.Grade
    and not exists (
      select 1 from tablename
      where customer_num = tt.customer_num and Grade = t.Grade and Month < tt.Month 
    )
  ) [Number of New Customer]
from tablename t
group by t.Grade, t.Month
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2ec820399e2f2ebaf8b3ba0ad05fd067).
Results:

```
> Grade | Month | Number of payment | Number of New Customer
> ----: | ----: | ----------------: | ---------------------:
>   100 |     5 |                 3 |                      1
>   100 |     6 |                 2 |                      0
>   200 |     6 |                 3 |                      1
>   200 |     7 |                 4 |                      2
```

Comment: Looks like that works, but may be less efficient than my answer?

Comment: @torpas I haven't run a benchmark, and I may be wrong, but if there were a large number of rows, I think the computation of [Number of New Customer] may be quite expensive, as it appears you have loops nested three levels deep - although an index may help.

Comment: How did you count 3 levels deep? The nested subquery has 2 levels and the 2nd level is the fastest there can be because it uses not exists which returns without scanning the whole table when it finds the value that it searches for. But your query uses group by 3 times and joins. It aggregates twice the table. Then joins and aggregates again on the results. Could it be more expensive?

Comment: By three levels I mean the outer loop is the select with the group clause, then the select count, finally the not exists check. That might take time N^3 time (where N is the size of the table). I think my answer would take time roughly proportional to N.

Conceptually I see my answer as constructing two tables ( each in roughly linear time ), then joining them together ( also in roughly linear time in size of the input ). Only a test would show if this is right in practice though.

Comment: *Only a test would show if this is right in practice though* but you did not do it and posted your first comment. Now about *linear time*. Since when a join would take N time? Also this is sql and sql code is executed with plans. Have you seen plans of code using group by? Do you know how expensive it is?

Comment: I just did some testing, it seems the two answers, as written, run in about the same time.

However: if I use a "HASH" hint ("inner hash join"), my answer runs much faster ( zero seconds, for my test on 12k records ). Without the hint it can run quite slowly.

Comment: I said "may be less efficient". With the "hash" hint that is true. I am surprised SQL server didn't select the most efficient way of doing the join. Perhaps if it ran on permanent tables it would. ( I did the test on a local copy of SQL server express edition )

Comment: Even  "may be less efficient" is not necessary to exist when it is not based in reallity.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does it, except your number of new customers in the first line should apparently be 1 not 3. Note: the "hash" hint seems to make this run much faster on 12k records.

```
select T.Grade, T.month, 
  sum(N) as [Number of payment], 
  sum(case when T.month=F.First then 1 else 0 end) as [Number of New Customer]
from
( select Grade, month, customer_num, count(*) as N from @table
  group by Grade, month, customer_num
) as T
inner hash join
( select customer_num, Grade, min(month) as First
  from @table group by customer_num, Grade
) as F on F.customer_num = T.customer_num and F.Grade = T.Grade
group by T.Grade, T.month
```

Comment: Good work, thanks for sharing this effective query.

Comment: @jishansiddique did you count how many times `group by` is used in this query?  So aggregating twice, then join and aggregating again. Do you know what this does to a query?

Comment: @forpas, you are right it's true but we have more options to perform the query.

Comment: @jishansiddique *more options*? Like what?

Comment: @forpas, like in your query you have created subquery.

Comment: And this subquery runs once for each row of the results of the main query and not once for each row of the table. So what is the problem? And what are the *options* that you mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

Use window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
select grade, year, month, count(*) as num_payment,
       count(distinct case when prev_ym is null then customer_num end) as num_new_customers
from (select t.*,
             min(year * 12 + month) over (partition by customer_num) as prev_ym
      from t
     ) t
group by grade, year, month;
```